# Could a photon also be a fermion?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, photons, angular-momentum, fermions

Some phycisits have found photons that has a spin of 1,5. Now fermions has always a half spin and bosons like photons always with a whole spin. But if those photons really exists are they than fermions?

http://www.sciencealert.com/physicists-just-discovered-a-new-form-of-light

In the other similar question is answered:
'this hints at a possible "fermionization" of photons in situations where J1/2J1/2 is a good operator, i.e. a description of the photonic system by an equivalent fermionic system.' But what is meant by fermionization? If a photon is measured a half can it be fermion or are there other conditions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Photons with half integer angular momentum - what's happening?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/256386/)

Comment: A photon is a photon. What you have in the above experiment are new quasi-particle states that are not photons.